# Reading constants into an SSE/AVX registers in inline assembly

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86-64, lazarus, avx

I'm trying to import a `.o` file from Lazarus into Delphi.

```
function Test: boolean;
const
  TestData: array[0..15] of byte = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
asm
  movdqu xmm0,[rip+testData]   //xmm0 should be all zeros
  pcmpeqq xmm1,xmm1        //xmm1 is all ones
  ptest xmm0,xmm1          //ZF = (xmm0 and xmm1) = 0
  setz al                  //return true if test works, false if not
end;
```

The above routine works in Delphi, but fails in Lazarus.

I'm importing the .o file using

```
   {$L 'C:\pathname\TestUnit.o'}

function TESTUNIT_TEST: boolean; external name 'TESTUNIT_$$_TEST$$BOOLEAN';
```

Lazarus replaces the reference to `TestData` with a zero offset.

```
AVXGENERATE_TEST:
//never mind the stack frame
0000000000A0F3B0 488D6424F8       lea rsp,[rsp-$08]
//                                                        rel 0? why?
0000000000A0F3B5 F30F6F0500000000 movdqu xmm0,dqword ptr [rel $00000000]
0000000000A0F3BD 660F3829C9       pcmpeqq xmm1,xmm1
0000000000A0F3C2 660F3817C1       ptest xmm0,xmm1
0000000000A0F3C7 0F94C0           setz al
0000000000A0F3CA 488D642408       lea rsp,[rsp+$08]
0000000000A0F3CF C3               ret
```

Here is the output from `objdump -dr "C:\pathname\TestUnit.o"

```
Disassembly of section .text.n_avxgenerate_$$_test$$boolean:

0000000000000000 <AVXGENERATE_$$_TEST$$BOOLEAN>:
   0:   48 8d 64 24 f8          lea    -0x8(%rsp),%rsp
   5:   f3 0f 6f 05 00 00 00    movdqu 0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # d <AVXGENERATE_$$_TEST$$BOOLEAN+0xd>
   c:   00
                        9: R_X86_64_PC32        .data.n_tc_$avxgenerate_$$_testdata
   d:   66 0f 38 29 c9          pcmpeqq %xmm1,%xmm1
  12:   66 0f 38 17 c1          ptest  %xmm1,%xmm0
  17:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  1a:   48 8d 64 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rsp
  1f:   c3
```

How do I get lazarus to read the constant correctly into an `xmm` register?
Is there a workaround for this issue?

I plan to include some `AVX` assembly written in lazarus in a Delphi program.
For testing purposes I'm just using `SSE` code here.

**Version info**
FPC 3.0.0
Lazarus version 1.6.2

Comment: Have you checked for relocation entries in the object file? `objdump -dr` ?

Comment: Not sure how that is supposed to answer my question. I have not told you to insert anything manually. I just asked if your object file (that you presumably have the dump from) includes relocation entries because then zero offset is normal.

Comment: @jester, I've included the output from `objdump`

Comment: Yeah there is the relocation entry all right. That should be filled in during linking.

Comment: How do I get a linked object file that I can link to `{$L 'file'}` in Delphi?

Comment: You don't. The final output from delphi should already be linked. Maybe whatever linking lazarus is doing can not handle relocations? Would be strange. As a workaround you can put your constant into the code section if your inline assembly has data definition directives.

Comment: Did you try to move `const TestData` outside the procedure, and write `movdqu xmm0,[rel testData]` instead for FPC ?

Comment: of course, `pxor xmm0,xmm0` would work with no constant ;)

Comment: Please always provide version info.

Comment: by bad: [rel testData] is a Delphi-only syntax; but I guess you may try to move the constant into the public "interface" of the unit

Comment: IIRC the "00000000" in the reference is valid, since it is resolved at linking

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, Yes, but why does Delphi not resolve the references when linking?

Comment: a good question to ask to EMB... I the Delphi Win64 linker to be a real PITA as soon as you need external references...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to put the routines to be imported into a DLL.
This means that you no longer have all your stuff in a standalone `.exe` file.
But at least all code links correctly.

**In Lazarus**

```
library Test_lib;

{$mode delphi}{$H+}

uses
  Classes,
  TestUnit;

{$R *.res}

exports
  Test;

begin
end.
```

**in Delphi**

```
const
  Testlib = 'C:\pathname\Lazarus\Test_lib.dll';

function LazarusTest: boolean; external Testlib name 'Test';
```

Now the output is:

```
0000000110020570 488D6424F8       lea rsp,[rsp-$08]
{                                 links to the correct location VVVVVV}
0000000110020575 F30F6F0553930000 movdqu xmm0,dqword ptr [rel $00009353]
000000011002057D 660F3829C9       pcmpeqq xmm1,xmm1
0000000110020582 660F3817C1       ptest xmm0,xmm1
0000000110020587 0F94C0           setz al
000000011002058A 488D642408       lea rsp,[rsp+$08]
000000011002058F C3               ret
```